# How do I join multiple files by awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Well, I have several files and I'm having trouble to join them with awk. 
Here are three sample files:

FileA

```
2   2   31771   15  5327353     4.73E-04    1   1
2   2   40642   23  27428869    -8.29E-04   1   1
2   2   21517   7   89002990    -2.41E-04   1   1
2   2   33787   16  44955568     2.86E-05   1   1
```

FileB

```
2   2   31771   15  5327353     5.07E-04    1   1
2   2   40642   23  27428869    5.45E-04    1   1
2   2   21517   7   89002990    1.85E-04    1   1
2   2   33787   16  44955568    3.73E-04    1   1
```

FileC

```
2   2   31771   15  5327353     4.28E-04    1   1
2   2   40642   23  27428869    -7.55E-04   1   1
2   2   21517   7   89002990    -2.01E-04   1   1
2   2   33787   16  44955568    3.09E-05    1   1
```

Each file has 8 columns, but I do not need columns 1, 2, 7 and 8. Columns 3, 4, and 5 are common to all files, these being perhaps the reference columns for joining the files, and column 6 would be the different information of each file. In general, my final file would look like this:

Finalfile

```
31771   15  5327353     4.73E-04    5.07E-04    4.28E-04
40642   23  27428869    -8.29E-04   5.45E-04    -7.55E-04
21517   7   89002990    -2.41E-04   1.85E-04    -2.01E-04
33787   16  44955568    2.86E-05    3.73E-04    3.09E-05
```

I tried the following commands:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$6;next}{print $3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"a[$3]}' FileA FileB FileC > Finalfile
```

But unfortunately it only works with two files, and I get something like this:

```
2   2   31771   15  5327353     4.73E-04    5.07E-04
2   2   40642   23  27428869    -8.29E-04   5.45E-04
2   2   21517   7   89002990    -2.41E-04   1.85E-04
2   2   33787   16  44955568    2.86E-05    3.73E-04
```

Can someone please help? Remember that there are multiple files (10), not just three. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
awk '{a[$3FS$4FS$5]=a[$3FS$4FS$5]""$6FS}END{for (i in a){print i, a[i]}}' file*
```

A *cleaner* version (Thanks @james-brown):

```
awk '{ a[$3 OFS $4 OFS $5 FS] = a[$3 OFS $4 OFS $5 FS] ( a[$3 OFS $4 OFS $5 FS] == "" ? "" : OFS) $6 }
     END{ for (i in a){print i,a[i]} }' OFS="\t"  file*
```

**Output**

```
33787   16  44955568    2.86E-05    3.73E-04    3.09E-05
21517   7   89002990    -2.41E-04   1.85E-04    -2.01E-04
40642   23  27428869    -8.29E-04   5.45E-04    -7.55E-04
31771   15  5327353     4.73E-04    5.07E-04    4.28E-04
```

Comment: I appreciate compactness more than the next guy but I'd probably `{ a[$3 OFS $4 OFS $5] = a[$3 OFS $4 OFS $5] ( a[$3 OFS $4 OFS $5] == "" ? "" : OFS) $6 }`. Other than that <3.

Comment: Yes quite more expressive @JamesBrown +1

Comment: Thanks, I apreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 3):

***paste*** + ***awk*** approach(with "pretty" output):

```
paste fileA fileB fileC | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$6,$14,$22}' | column -tx
```

The output:

```
31771  15  5327353   4.73E-04   5.07E-04  4.28E-04
40642  23  27428869  -8.29E-04  5.45E-04  -7.55E-04
21517  7   89002990  -2.41E-04  1.85E-04  -2.01E-04
33787  16  44955568  2.86E-05   3.73E-04  3.09E-05
```